# What is the difference between GPE and gravitational self energy in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

What is the difference between gravitational potential energy and gravitational self energy in General Relativity? Are they both the same in Newtonian gravity?

Comment: this may help :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#General_relativity

Comment: Is GPE used in General Relativity?